# With Eclipselink/JPA, can I have a Foreign Composite Key that shares a field with a Primary Composite Key?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

My database has two entities; Company and Person. A Company can have many People, but a Person must have only one Company. The table structure looks as follows.

```
COMPANY
----------
owner   PK
comp_id PK
c_name
```

```
PERSON
----------------
owner    PK, FK1
personid PK
comp_id  FK1
p_fname
p_sname
```

It has occurred to me that I could remove PERSON.OWNER and derive it through the foreign key; however, I can't make this change without affecting legacy code.

I have modeled these as JPA-annotated classes;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@IdClass(PersonPK.class)
public class Person
    implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String owner;

  @Id
  private String personid;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns(
    {@JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "OWNER",
                 insertable = false, updatable = false),
     @JoinColumn(name = "comp_id", referencedColumnName = "COMP_ID",
                 insertable = true, updatable = true)})
  private Company company;

  private String p_fname;

  private String p_sname;

  ...and standard getters/setters...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
@IdClass(CompanyPK.class)
public class Company
    implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String owner;

  @Id
  private String comp_id;

  private String c_name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List people;

  ...and standard getters/setters...
}
```

My PersonPK and CompanyPK classes are nothing special, they just serve as a struct holding owner and the ID field, and override hashCode and equals(o).

So far so good. I come across a problem, however, when trying to deal with associations. It seems if I have an existing Company, and create a Person, and associate to the Person to the Company and persist the company, the association is not saved when the Person is inserted. For example, my main code looks like this:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

CompanyPK companyPK = new CompanyPK();
companyPK.owner="USA";
companyPK.comp_id="1102F3";
Company company = em.find(Company.class, companyPK);

Person person = new Person();
person.setOwner("USA");
person.setPersonid("5116628123"); //some number that doesn't exist yet
person.setP_fname("Hannah");
person.setP_sname("Montana");
person.setCompany(company);
em.persist(person);
```

This completes without error; however in the database I find that the Person record was inserted with a null in the COMP_ID field. With EclipseLink debug logging set to FINE, the SQL query is shown as:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSONID,OWNER,P_SNAME,P_FNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
  bind => [5116628123,USA,Montana,Hannah,]
```

I would have expected this to be saved, and the query to be equivalent to

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSONID,OWNER,COMP_ID,P_SNAME,P_FNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
  bind => [5116628123,USA,1102F3,Montana,Hannah,]
```

What gives? Is it incorrect to say updatable/insertable=true for one half of a composite key and =false for the other half? If I have updatable/insertable=true for both parts of the foreign key, then Eclipselink fails to startup saying that I can not use the column twice without having one set to readonly by specifying these options.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should work.  Ensure you recompiled/deployed it correctly.
What version are you using?

Also ensure that your Company object has a valid id set.

You could also try putting ,

```
insertable = false, updatable = false
```

in your owner field's @Column and leave the entire foreign key insertable/updatable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And the solution i've found is to anotate primary key fields as non-insertable and non-updatable. Your person entity should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@IdClass(PersonPK.class)
public class Person
    implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable=false)
  private String owner;

  @Id
  private String personid;

  @Id
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable=false)
  private String comp_id;


  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "OWNER"),
     @JoinColumn(name = "comp_id", referencedColumnName = "COMP_ID")
  })
  private Company company;

  private String p_fname;

  private String p_sname;

  ...and standard getters/setters...
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is the effect of doing this? At what stage does (say) the owner attribute get set with its value?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to annotate the fields in the PK class like I would have if they were on the entity.

Then in the entity don't have the fields the PK class holds.  If you want to you can implement getters that passthrough

```
class Person {
  .....

private PersonPK pk;

@Id
public PersonPK getPk() { return pk; }

@Transient
public String getOwner() {
  return pk.getOwner();
}
....
}
```

The PersonPK needs to be serializable and annoted `@Embeddable`

```
@Embeddable
class PersonPK implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the databases design being rather weird, this might work:

```
@Entity
public class Company
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompanyPK key;

    @MapsId(value = "ownerId")
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "personid")
    private Person owner;

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Person> persons;

    @Column(name = "c_name")
    private String name;
}

@Embeddable
public class CompanyPK
{
    @Column(name = "comp_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String ownerId;
}

@Entity
public class Person
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonPK key;

    @MapdId(value = "ownerId")
    private Person owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "owner")
        @JoinColumn(name = "comp_id", referencedColumnName = "comp_id")
    })
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "p_fname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "p_sname")
    private String surName;
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonPK
{
    @Column(name = "personid")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String ownerId;
}
```