# JPA and a novice's issue with relationship-mapping

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to get the following type of mapping to work

```
Table event has the following columns:
id (PK)
prodgroup
errandtype

table errandtype : errandtype

table prodgroup: prodgroup
```

I have corresponding JPA classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class MyEvent {
    @Id
    int id;

    // what mapping should go here?
    Prodgroup prodgroup;

    // what mapping should go here?
    ErrandType errandtype;
} 

@Entity
public class Prodgroup {
    @Id
    private String prodgroup;
}

@Entity
public class ErrandType {
    @Id
    private String errandtype;
}
```

Ok so questions are marked as comments in the code but I'll try to be explicit anyway.

In the above example I want my Prodgroup and ErrandType fields in the MyEvent class to be set to corresponding Prodgroup and Errandtype instances

I have tried @OneToOne relationships with @joincolumns and with mappedby attribute, but I just can't get it working and I've lost all sense of logical approach. My grasp of JPA entity mapping is clearly weak.

So can anyone bring some clarity?

Comment: Do you generate tables out of your JPA classes? Or you are trying to map to existing tables?

Comment: @user1697575 I am trying to map to existing tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class MyEvent {
    @Id
    int id;

    // what mapping should go here?
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prodgroup_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    Prodgroup prodgroup;

    // what mapping should go here?
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "errandtype_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    ErrandType errandtype;
} 

@Entity
public class Prodgroup {
    @Id
    private String prodgroup;
}

@Entity
public class ErrandType {
    @Id
    private String errandtype;
}
```

FetchType Eager means the object will be always loaded (would be "Lazy" by default if not specified).
CascadeType.ALL means mearge/persist/remove will be also done to linked tables.

Sebastian

Comment: I would also do something like this. But I don't see any reason to use FetchType_EAGER in this case. In fact, you should avoid using it, unless it's completely necessary due to performance issues.

Comment: Default value for fetch in @ManyToOne annotation is EAGER. So explicit FetchType.EAGER does not have effect (of course it is can be useful reminder if API is not well known).

Comment: This answer was conceptually correct, and basically solved my problem. In order to get it working all the way I had to surrogate the errandtype and prodgroup keys. The PKs then became Integer compatible which was required according to an error message I received. How do I use single String type PKs? For multi-column PKs theres a concept @Embedable but must I use such a class also for single-column but non-Integer PKs?

Comment: Yes I think you will need to use @Embeddable, see for example this Thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232977/1448704

Comment: But please open a new Thread on that specific topic, and I guess you might receive a more elegant answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your table columns `event.prodgroup` and `event.errandtype` are foreign keys to respective tables (prodgroup, errandtype). So you need [@ManyToOne](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne) association (because many events may share one prodgroup or errantype).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The problem I saw with this relation is that in the Java view of things it was really a one to one mapping because its no parent child relationship (i.e there was no collection on either side). But JPA annotations clearly then should relate to the datamodel concept.

Comment: @Rythmic If it is a one-to-one association it should be also possible to do with `@OneToOne`. I don't know your system, but are you sure that this is really a one-to-one association (ie. a particular prodgroup or errandtype can be used by at most *one* event?).

Comment: no it is clearly a ManyToOne association as both a certain errandtype and prodgroup can exist in many rows of the event table. The thing was that all examples showing ManyToOne relationships had that parent child perspective where the parent had a collection of children. In my case each event has exactly one errand type and one prodgroup so there were no collections in either of the entity classes. Anyway it was solved using the solution above as a guide. So the solution was clearly ManyToOne which earned you the upvote :) Thank you for your time.